# NiFi process groups performance (output ports)

Tags: apache-nifi

I use NiFi process groups to simplify the view of the entire process.
However, to use process groups, we have to pass the output to an output port and then the next processor has to be fed from that process group "via" the output port.

I have noticed that I experience performance degradation when I do that. It seems that the downstream processors are waiting for the output port to send files although the files are "available" in the upstream process groups' output port.

I removed the process groups and directly connected the processors and I see a drastic improvement in the flows. Although this looks messy and unreadable (that's the purpose of using process groups).

There is no configuration available in output port and it seems like just a passthrough mecahnism(it should be) but I am not sure why is it acting as a bottleneck.

Any views or insight on this would be very helpful

1) Option that is slower: Input -----> A Process Group(Containing Input port+Extract text+Replace text+Output port) ------> Output

2) Faster performing flow: Input ------->Extract text+Replace text ------------> Output

Comment: Can you add some diagram information?

Comment: Option that is slower:
Input -----> A Process Group(Containing Input port+Extract text+Replace text+Output port) ------> Output

Faster performing flow:
Input ------->Extract text+Replace text ------------> Output

Comment: How did you take the measures? can you add the template to be able to recreate your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [thread](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/100346/how-to-speed-up-nifi-flowfile-transfer-from-proces.html) about this on HCC.

Some things to look into:

1. If there is too much in the queues, swapping may occur
2. Timer based microbatching is used to move data between processes groups, this in itself should not add significant overhead, but you will want to make sure that you set Maximum Timer Driven Thread Count high enough